# Mach-0 Linker error when trying to run watchKit app on Simulator

Tags: ios, watchkit

When I try to build and run my app with a watchKit extension, here is the error screen that I see. If you would like to see a larger image, simply right click and hit open in new Tab. [image]

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party library? Try to link with libc++.dylib

Comment: I do use 3rd party libraries. Would I have to link the watchKit target with the libc++.dylib?

Comment: I think so. Could you share with what library are you linking?

Answer (score 0):

This mean i386 architecture don't undefined this function.

so I think that x-code update or define header again.

Comment: Im not sure Im understanding your answer.

Comment: this error write
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
std::string::find(char const*, unsigned long) const .. bulabula..

this i386 is x-code simulator machine.
And x-code support NSString instread of string(CString).

I think you convert code string to NSString

Comment: Could you give more details on how to convert the code?

Comment: NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init]; // string *str; or char *str;

str = @"take"; // str = "take";

this is very simple.. but if you want to use api, plz google search NSString